# margin: 0 auto not centering?

Tags: css

I've tried the following code in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, but my div isn't quite being centered.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <link href="custom.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head> 
<body>  
    <div class="center">Hello!</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

custom.css:

```
.center {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

This produces the following in Chrome:
[image]

and you can see that the left margin is bigger than the right margin.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that your full `custom.css` file? What does the `padding` on your `<html>` and `<body>` look like?

Comment: Yeah, that was my full custom.css file. I didn't realize there were default padding or margins on html and body, so Time Machine's answer fixed it.

Comment: have fun! Oh, don't forget to click the green checkmark before a zombie eats you, as it's Halloween. :)

Comment: @Time Machine: yep, I was waiting for the 10 minute mark to pass :). Thanks!

Comment: If this happened to a button, img, input etc., just set the display property of that to block. Ex. button{display:block}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is because the body has a margin (default for browsers):

```
body { margin: 0px; }
```

You might want to use a [CSS reset](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/).

---

It should look normal if your window is bigger. In your screenshot it's like:

[image: mug]

Comment: Is it OK to apply `body { margin: 0 auto; }` to center the page, or should we be adding a `div` wrapper with an ID to avoid some sort of bugs? Thanks! For example, here it suggests to use #wrapper, and also apply `text-align: center` to the body: http://www.webdesignerforum.co.uk/topic/2473-tutorial-how-to-center-a-site-using-css/ (but doesn't really explain it well)

Answer (score 2):

The window is too narrow. Auto margins centre elements in the available space, if the space is narrower than the element, then it becomes left aligned.

So, from left to right you see the padding or margin on the body element (margin in this case as it is Chrome), then the border for the div, then the 400px of width, then the next border, and then the window edge as there isn't any more space to render the body's right margin.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble getting buttons to center in chrome. giving width to the buttons will work.
But this causes an issue with all the buttons having a width.

This fix seems to be playing happy in the browsers.
The main fix would be to give the input type buttons a width, that works, but when you have a large web app managing all those may not be feasible.

Found this, yes it is a hack, but appears to be working in IE7-9 FF chrome.

```
.submitArea .actButton  {margin-right: auto !important; margin-left: auto !important; display: block;}
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { .submitArea .actButton  {display: inline-block !important;}}  /* chrome hack - needs width for buttons to center */
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to add relative positioning to your css.

```
.center {
 position:relative;
 width: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 5px solid black;
}
```