# display block, margins auto, width specified, not centering

Tags: css

```
.DOC {
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:1265px;
}
```

`.DOC` is a `div` inside the `body` tag, but it's not centering. Why is this?

Comment: What you are asking... you want to align div to center...? or why this code does not align the div to center...?

Comment: What is the element with the .doc class?

Comment: Is your markup exactly `class="DOC"`? maybe it's an ID('#DOC'), or lower case (`.doc`)

Comment: Please include a complete document.

Comment: YEAH! Give us the HTML, we wants it!

Comment: Tryied this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4060491/133408 ?

Comment: tried clearing your cache? cos the code works for me in chrome,IE9 and FF

Comment: nothing wrong with what you've posted.  try digging a little deeper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work

see http://jsfiddle.net/yWkyE/

```
.DOC
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color:#000000;
}
```

Is there any other CSS in play on the page that might be affecting this DIV? What's your HTML like, could you provide a sample?

Answer (score 2):

Your width is *potentially* the problem. Try setting it to something small for development purposes such as 100px.

See here, http://jsfiddle.net/tJd5M/

```
.DOC {
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:100px;
  background:orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Style works fine for me...

**Adding Border will show is the Div in Center of the page or Not...**

```
.DOC {
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:1265px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

and if you want **to align the Content of Div to Center** then try the below style

```
.DOC {
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:1265px;
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div  class="DOC">Sample Text</div>
```

**Better you decrease your width and try.... it will show the Accuracy**